# jQuery timepicker throwing exception that is not triggered by my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am constantly getting this error on console saying my timepicker can't read property `find`. But the stack trace doesn't even have my JavaScript file function. All of them is happening in jQuery itself. Is this something I did wrong? I reverted around 20 commits, but this is still happening.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas? Where do I even start to debug this? `try` / `catch` on any of my code doesn't throw exception and break point on any line of my code doesn't do anything.

```
$(('#alternateDayStartTime'+i)).timepicker(alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting)
$(('#alternateDayEndTime'+i)).timepicker(alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting)

var alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting = {
    'timeFormat' : 'g:i A',
    'noneOption' : {
        label : "None",
        value : ""
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
In case anyone is curious, this ends up being a very different problem than time picker itself. I haven't figure out exactly what caused it but I found a solution by disabling another section of code in specific conditions. I will add an update after I find out what exactly went wrong

Comment: You'll need to post the code where you make use of this plugin instead of just an image.

Comment: It sounds like the plugin is expecting a jQuery object, but receiving `undefined`. Are you perhaps using an invalid selector?

Comment: Have you placed your code in document ready.?

Comment: @Santi added the initialization. There is a onchange call back but doesn't quite do anything even if I chagne it to console.log

Comment: @Nimish I did.:(

Comment: This isn't the entirety of the code - what is `i`? It sounds like you're calling `timepicker` on an `undefined`, meaning one of your selectors could be wrong (as @DavidHedlund mentioned). If you replace the selectors for your `.timepicker` with an element that you *know* exists (like a static `id` on the page), does the error disappear?

Comment: works here https://jsfiddle.net/gtLvys4w/. make sure your `i` is correct.

Comment: @Santi I added a `console.log($(('#alternateDayEndTime'+i)))` before every time I call .timepicker None of them is undefined

Comment: @Santi `undefined.timepicker()
VM14528:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:10`    This is the error message for undefined. Not exactly same for me

Comment: Well despite our stab-in-the-dark attempts to fix this, we're not going to be able to help you much further unless you edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Per [On-Topic (1):](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself."*

Comment: @Santi Lol thanks anyways. All my attempts to reproduce turns out working fine. If I am able to reproduce this in an environment other than more than 10k line of production code I would've fixed it by now. But yeah ik this is vague but honestly I don't have a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of 'JavaScript hoisting'.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Move the code:

```
var alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting = {
    'timeFormat' : 'g:i A',
    'noneOption' : {
        label : "None",
        value : ""
    }
}
```

Above

```
$(('#alternateDayStartTime'+i)).timepicker(alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting)
$(('#alternateDayEndTime'+i)).timepicker(alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting)
```

Like so:

```
var alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting = {
    'timeFormat' : 'g:i A',
    'noneOption' : {
        label : "None",
        value : ""
    }
}

$(('#alternateDayStartTime'+i)).timepicker(alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting)
$(('#alternateDayEndTime'+i)).timepicker(alternateScheduleTimePickerSetting)
```

Comment: I actually have the setting above the actual usage. it's not this causing it

Comment: Where do you declare 'i'?

Comment: in a normal for loop. setting is on the top, right after document ready, and all the rest is in a for loop with index i

Comment: Why are you doing double parantheses? $(('#alternateDayStartTime'+i))?  Should be $('#alternateDayStartTime'+i)

Comment: Making sure the string gets contated first? but that doesn't matter. Either way still having the issue

Comment: You're going to need to post more code.  Could be anything.. Maybe it's a closure issue.